# Recreating a guilloche with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

One of my last questions talked about [certificates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46406/10898) and I got great answers. Now my questions is, can one recreate a guilloche in TikZ like the one shown below:[image]

or may be a border like

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41159/does-anybody-know-a-good-source-of-free-ornaments-decorations-frames-backgr

Comment: And/or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36352/spirograph-continuous-rotations-in-tikz-or-pstricks ?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for reference I thought I'd add this, since I stumbled across it. It might be possible to design a desirable guilloche with this http://www.subblue.com/projects/guilloche and then utilising their provided source code (extract the equations), plug parameters from your drawing to re-create the image with TikZ

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> Guilloché (Guilloche) is a decorative engraving technique in which a
>   very precise intricate repetitive pattern or design is mechanically
>   engraved into an underlying material with fine detail. Specifically,
>   it involves a technique of engine turning, called guilloché in French
>   after the French engineer “Guillot”, who invented a machine “that
>   could scratch fine patterns and designs on metallic surfaces

The problem is to draw a curve with a fixed point inside a circle

A method : I used tkz-fct because it's my package and I know it but it's easy to create the same thing with only tikz. (here you need gnuplot)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}     
\usepackage{tkz-fct}


\begin{document} 

\def\spirographlike#1{%
\def\repeatno{#1}
 \foreach \i in {1,...,\repeatno}
   {%
    \begin{scope}[rotate=360/\repeatno*\i]
      \mycloedcurve
    \end{scope}}%
    } 

\def\mycloedcurve{\tkzFctPolar[color=MidnightBlue,thick,domain=0:2*pi,samples=400]{ 1+cos(3*t)+(sin(3*t))**2}}  

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
 \mycloedcurve 
\end{tikzpicture}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
 \tkzInit [xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5] 
  \spirographlike{40}    
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

**update**

[image]
This is better but you need some time to compile

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}     
\usepackage{tkz-fct}


\begin{document} 

\def\spirographlike#1{%
\def\repeatno{#1}
 \foreach \i in {1,...,\repeatno}
   {%
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={360/\repeatno*\i:(.5,0)}]
      \mycloedcurve
    \end{scope}}%
    } 

\def\mycloedcurve{\tkzFctPolar[color=MidnightBlue,thick,domain=0:2*pi,samples=400]{ 1+cos(3*t)+(sin(3*t))**2}}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \mycloedcurve 
\end{tikzpicture}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
 \tkzInit [xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5] 
  \spirographlike{20}    
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sweet sweet sweet.....love TikZ.....love it <3.

Comment: Adding `\noindent` before `\begin{tikzpicture}` eliminates the `overfull \hbox` warning.

Comment: Thanks Peter I forget always these kind of problem, because I'm obsessed with the main question. Possible `\usepackage{fullpage}`

Comment: Very nice. This is getting closer and closer to the [Spirograph question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36352/3235).

Comment: @percusse Can you provide any insights in generating the border like guilloche? Or may be with your knowledge on your post quoted above can the image sample I provided be recreated?

Comment: @percusse yes you are right. I only change one thing it's the point of rotation for the second picture ( and the curve ! )

Comment: @azetina I think what is above is fantastic anyway. What you are asking requires a closed form formula for the end product. If you can provide those formulas or the initial shapes you can plug them into the code of Altermundus above.

Comment: Exactly percusse is right, you need to find the good formula or a find a shape to rotate. I made some tries but this takes a lot of time.

Comment: @percusse I agree with what you are saying. This applies to the rotation examples but how about the horizontal like shape borders. My guess would involve `sin` and `cos`but then to decide where to cut it off and it being dependent on a length would be the trick.

Comment: FYI,   
I have posted instructions on how to install gnuplot, and make it talk to latex, on Mac OS X here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71160/how-to-use-gnu-plot-to-plot-diagrams-in-texshop?lq=1

Answer (score 18):

So here's an approach to draw the 'straight' parts. (Might be a bit crude to more seasoned people...)

The compile time is certain to put the most patient of us to test, but that's to be expected with `TikZ` doing such things... `:)`

I only plotted one such sample from the ones I found at [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GuillochePattern.html). So there are some samples ready to be downloaded. They are (as you can see below) a sum of lots of sines and the essential trick to get them to mesh together beautifully is to control the 'frequency' and the 'initial phase'.

So here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thin]

\foreach \n in {0,...,19}
    {
        \foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0)] in {0.01,0.02,...,6.28}
            {
                \draw [red] (\lastx*2,{(4+sin(5*(180*\lastx/pi)))+((7+sin(7*(180*\lastx/pi)))-(4+sin(5*(180*\lastx/pi))))*(1+sin(5*(180*\lastx/pi)+\n*20))/2}) -- (\x*2,{(4+sin(5*(180*\x/pi)))+((7+sin(7*(180*\x/pi)))-(4+sin(5*(180*\x/pi))))*(1+sin(5*(180*\x/pi)+\n*20))/2});
            }
    }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I had to rescale a bit the coordinates, primarily because the source formulas used radians and `TikZ` likes degrees... Also I stretched a bit the thing along the `x` axis for looks.

And this is what you get after - well - a while:

[image]

### Faster Code:

The idea is to reuse the previous coordinate instead of recomputing it with the use of `\lastx`. Further this means that there will only be `{0,...,19}` draw commands instead of `20\times6.29/0.01=12580`.
This feature is used by doing an inline for-loop.

So instead you would do:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thin]

  \foreach \n in {0,...,19} {
      \draw [red] (0,{(4+sin(5*(0)))+((7+sin(7*(0)))-(4+sin(5*(0))))*(1+sin(5*(0)+\n*20))/2}) 
      \foreach \x in {0.01,0.02,...,6.28} { 
          -- (\x*2,{(4+sin(5*(180*\x/pi)))+((7+sin(7*(180*\x/pi)))-(4+sin(5*(180*\x/pi))))*(1+sin(5*(180*\x/pi)+\n*20))/2}) 
      }; % <- Here the \draw ends
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For further speed the computation of the angles could be made more explicit, and shorter expression could be made:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thin]
  \foreach \n in {0,...,19} {
      \draw [red] (0,{4+(7-4)*(1+sin(\n*20))/2}) 
      \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,360} { 
          -- ({6.28318*\x/180},{4+sin(5*\x)+(7+sin(7*\x)-(4+sin(5*\x)))*(1+sin(5*\x+\n*20))/2})
      };
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As a last optimization all variables that can be reduced should be, this will not give as much, as it is *simple* multiplication and division:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thin]
  \foreach \n [evaluate={\n*20} as \ntwenty] in {0,...,19} {
      \draw [red] (0,{5.5+1.5*sin(\ntwenty))}) 
      \foreach \x [evaluate={sin(5*\x)} as \sfx] in {0.5,1,...,360} { 
          -- ({0.034906585039886591*\x},{4+\sfx+(3+sin(7*\x)-\sfx)*(1+sin(5*\x+\ntwenty))/2})
      };
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And actually it does compiler twice as fast, and faster for the last, when changing from `evaluate` to `\pgfextra\pgfmathparse{sin(5*\x)}\edef\sfx{\pgfmathresult}\endpgfextra` there is no gain, so is not showed:

1. 1m59.699s
2. 0m59.100s
3. 0m43.627s
4. 0m38.714s

Comment: Excellent results. I suppose one can make it into border like with the above. Though the compilation may take long one can export  it as a pdf and then import it as a background.

Comment: Very nice, the compilation time will be speed up a lot by not calculating every point twice, so instead do: `\draw [red] (\lastx*2,{(4+sin(5*(180*\lastx/pi)))+((7+sin(7*(180*\lastx/pi)))-(4+sin(5*(180*\lastx/pi))))*(1+sin(5*(180*\lastx/pi)+\n*20))/2})
      \foreach \x in {0.01,0.02,...,6.28} {
          -- (\x*2,{(4+sin(5*(180*\x/pi)))+((7+sin(7*(180*\x/pi)))-(4+sin(5*(180*\x/pi))))*(1+sin(5*(180*\x/pi)+\n*20))/2})
      };` also the `180*\x/pi` could be automated in the for loop instead!

Comment: @zeroth: I'm sorry, I don't really get it... Where do I insert that line of code? What should I do with `\lastx`? I'd rather you edited my answer (if it's too much for a comment).

Comment: @CountZero I have edited your answer with two speedups! :)

Comment: @CountZero and one more, which only is to illustrate that the fewest repetitive computations is the best! :)

Comment: @zeroth: THX! `:)`

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to creating guillochés with TikZ is to use a third-party tool to produce them as graphics files, and then import them into your document using the usual `\includegraphics{…}`.

I'm aware of the following guilloché tools:

## [GuardSoft Cerberus](http://www.guard-soft.com/cerberus.html)

A sophisticated, proprietary guilloché tool for Microsoft Windows that can export to PostScript.  Prices are not listed on the website, though I gather that it's very expensive (thousands of dollars).

[image: Screenshot of GuardSoft Cerberus]

## [Excentro](http://www.excourse.com/excentro/)

Another proprietary Guilloché generator, available for $500 for Mac OS.  There is also a "Lite" version available for $25.  Bitmap and PDF outputs are supported.

[image: Screenshot of Excentro]

## [Guilloché Pattern Generator](http://2008.sub.blue/projects/guilloche.html)

A free-as-in-beer Adobe Flash application that you can use from a web browser.  You simply select the desired foreground and background colours and adjust a series of sliders to control the size and shape of the pattern.  The patterns can be saved as JPEG images by pressing `S`.  If your system has a printer driver that outputs PDF files, then you can supposedly print vectorized PDFs by right-clicking and selecting "Print Guilloche".  (I haven't tested this myself.)

[image: Screenshot of subblue's Guilloché Pattern Generator]

## [Vectorizer](http://blackholedesign.com/vectorizer/)

A reimplementation of subblue's Guilloché Pattern Generator in HTML and JavaScript.  It can output the image as a PNG or SVG graphic.  (You can then use your favourite graphics converter, such as [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) or [rsvg](https://github.com/jeroenooms/rsvg), to convert the SVG to PDF or EPS for use with LaTeX.)

[image: Screenshot of Vectorizer]