# Mathematica code into TikZ code

Tags: tikz-pgf, wolfram-mathematica

In my search to understand the creation of a guilloche and in relation to my post [Recreating a guilloche with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46507/10898), I came about the code below,

```
 Guilloche[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_] := 
 PolarPlot[Evaluate[Flatten[{ Table[(c + Sin[a x + d]) + ((b + Sin[b x + e]) - (c + Sin[a x + d]))(f + Sin[a x + n/ Pi])/2, {n, 0, 19}] }] ], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 200, Axes -> None, Frame -> False]

 Guilloche[4, 8, 20, 4.7, 1.8, 1];
```

Written in Mathematica which should produce the following image:[image]

My attempt below compiles but with no image.

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}     
 \usepackage{tkz-fct}


 \begin{document}
 \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \i in {1,...,19}{%
 \tkzFctPolar[color=MidnightBlue,thick,domain=0:2*pi,samples=400]{(4 + sin(4*t + 4.7)) +((8 + sin(8*t + 1.8)) - (20 + sin(4*t + 4.7)))
 (1 + sin(4*t + \i/ Pi))/2}}   
 \end{tikzpicture} 

 \end{document}
```

Any assistance on how to convert the code appropriately will be highly appreciated. In general, the Mathematica code should produce different guilloches but I don't know how I would be able to implement it into `TikZ` to generate different guilloches from one piece of code.

Comment: You get no image because your setting for xmin xmax ymin ymax and xstep, ystep are wrong. You take the values by default. You need to give a try to pgplots because my tools are rudimentary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a problem of units. You can use mathematica or excel or maxima or a free soft to calculate some values. After it's easy to find how to setup `\tkzInit`. Perhaps it's more easy with pgfplots.

[image]

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}     
 \usepackage{tkz-fct}


 \begin{document}
 \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzInit[xmin=-50,xmax=50,ymin=-50,ymax=50,xstep=5,ystep=5]
 \foreach \i in {1,...,19}{%
 \tkzFctPolar[color=MidnightBlue,thick,domain=0:4*pi,samples=400]{
 (20 + sin(4*t + 4.7)) +  ((8 + sin(8*t + 1.8)) - (20 + sin(4*t + 4.7)))*
 (1 + sin(4*t + \i/ 3.14))/2}}   
 \end{tikzpicture} 

 \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzInit[xmin=-50,xmax=50,ymin=-50,ymax=50,xstep=5,ystep=5]
 \foreach \i in {1,...,10}{%
 \tkzFctPolar[color=MidnightBlue,thick,domain=0:4*pi,samples=400]{
 (10 + sin(4*t + 4.7)) +  ((4 + sin(4*t + 1.8)) - (10 + sin(4*t + 4.7)))*
 (1 + sin(4*t + \i/ 3.14))/2}}   
 \end{tikzpicture} 

 \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzInit[xmin=-50,xmax=50,ymin=-50,ymax=50,xstep=5,ystep=5]
 \foreach \i in {1,...,19}{%
 \tkzFctPolar[color=MidnightBlue,thick,domain=0:4*pi,samples=400]{
 (15 + sin(4*t + 4.7)) +  ((8 + sin(8*t + 1.8)) - (15 + sin(4*t + 4.7)))*
 (1.5 + sin(4*t + \i/ 3.14))/2}}   
 \end{tikzpicture}       

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate the correction. By the way what do you think about this method for generating the guilloche? Interesting right? I am still learning and trying to understand how this thing works. My ultimate goal is to recreate the image I had on my first post [Recreating a guilloche with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46507/10898). Take a look at this [post](http://www.subblue.com/blog/2008/10/10/guilloche).

Comment: Yes very interesting. I think you can get the initial picture but you need to find other shapes and after you can put all the results together. You can fix `\i` to 1. and you get the initial shape and after you need to make some  tries

Comment: When I replied on my first comment I hadn't tried to compile the code above since in your post you had the image. I tried it a while ago and I can't seem to get the compilation to produce the image. Why?

Comment: I get the picture in 3s with pdflatex mactex 2011 pgf 2.1 cvs but I tried also with pgf 2.1 from TL and the result is fine. I update my answer with other pictures.

Comment: I just tried it, too, and your MWE does not return an image in the PDF. The log-file shows the following error-message, which is not thrown as a LaTeX-warning though: `runsystem(gnuplot guilloche.tkzpolarfct.gnuplot)...disabled (restricted). Package pgf Warning: Plot data file 'guilloche.tkzpolarfct.table' not found. on
 input line 12.` I'm running MaxTex 2011, but don't have `gnuplot` installed. Maybe the OP is missing it, too?

Comment: @Daniel you are in restricted mode. You need to allow tex to load gnuplot so you need to work with "\write18 enabled". You need to compile with --shell-escape or sometimes --enable-write18

Comment: You need to gnuplot and you need to compile with --shell-escape option. There are a lot of answers about these problems here on on the net.

Comment: @Altermundus I don't get this thing about `write18`. How do I do it on Windows with Miktex 2.9 and Winedt? Or can you redirect me to a post that explains it. I am currently searching but a help here would be appreciated.

Comment: On the site you can search with write18 or shell-escape. For example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/how-can-i-enable-write-18-on-a-miktex-installation .  I describe how to do in the documentation of tkz-fct page 12. The explanation is in french but the line of code are universal.

Comment: I followed the link you provided but then I get the following error `Package pgf Warning: Plot data file guilloche.tkzpolarfct.table' not found.'gnuplot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: There are three problems with gnuplot on Windows : 1) the name of gnuplot (sometimes you need to change the name 2) the PATH gnuplot is not found if the PATH is not correct and 3) enable write18 . I upload on my site a document from a german user of the tkz packages : http://altermundus.com/SandBox/tkz_use.pdf

Comment: What does the tutorial part `For use with MiKTeX, copy the file 'pgnuplot.exe' in the /bin directory to 'gnuplot.exe'` mean?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2701/discussion-between-azetina-and-altermundus)