# Illuminated manuscripts & LaTeX

Tags: text-decorations, decorations, drop-cap

How can I produce *Illuminated manuscripts* (something like [this](https://www.google.it/search?hl=it&tok=rEzYVSHWul4VNZGaIdAuSg&cp=23&gs_id=f&xhr=t&q=illuminated%20manuscripts&safe=off&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&ion=1&biw=1152&bih=620&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=g6EqUICOFYbhtQaahICYAw))?

Are there existing examples of illuminated manuscripts made with latex, or websites that provide initials or decorations with this style?

Comment: Perhaps this is of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/24719#24719

Comment: The [LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/otherfonts.html) lists some 'decorative' fonts that might be of interest.  In terms of the border decorations and so forth, those were done by hand; there are no obvious 'templates' (in TeX) for such things.  I would draw those in another program, or by hand, and then use them as a watermark image on your document.

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46507/recreating-a-guilloche-with-tikz ?