# How to use GNU Plot to plot diagrams in TexShop

Tags: gnuplot, texshop

hope anyone can help with this... I have a very basic knowledge of TeXShop, but I need to plot some functions on it, say `y=x`. I learnt that this can be done by installing GNU Plot and writing in TeXShop

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
    \draw[color=black] plot[id=x] function{x} 
        node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So I have downloaded GNU Plot and dragged it from the disk image to applications. I don't know how to use it but it's there. However when I run the above in TeXShop only the axis and labels pop up, but no function!

I have read many sites now, but it all seems too complicated for me - can anyone help?

Comment: I think you need X11 wich apple calls xquartz and you will need aquaterm i dont know why. thats what i found on google but apparently it does not help me either :( i can open gnuplot from the terminal and plot with aquaterm but i still cant see the plot in texshop anybody knows what i have to do ?

Comment: If you want to plot functions using LaTeX/tikz, you may be interested in pgfplots, compare http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 12):

Here is what I did to get `gnuplot` working on a Mac.  (You need to use the Terminal for this.)

Goto [GNU Plot on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/) and download the source code.  This should unzip in a folder `gnuplot-4.6.0` in your Downloads folder.

Open a Terminal window and issue the following commands: (hit the return key after each; the last three commands will produce quite a bit of terminal output and you'll need to wait for them to be done before issuing the next command.)

```
cd ~/Downloads/gnuplot-4.6.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

This will correctly install GNUPlot on your machine.

Now in TeXShop, you can make a simple document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4] 
    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
    \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$}; 
    \draw[color=black] plot[id=x] function{x} node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4] 
    \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
    \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
    \draw[color=red] plot[id=x] function{x} node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
    \draw[color=blue] plot[id=sin] function{sin(x)} node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$}; 
    \draw[color=orange] 
        plot[id=exp] function{0.05*exp(x)} node[right] {$f(x) = \frac{1}{20} \mathrm e^x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Run this with TeXShop.  You should get the following output:

[image: output of code]

Comment: Does this code actually use `gnuplot`?

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes.  If you try to compile the document without `gnuplot` installed, you get garbage.

Comment: Ok, but for some reason I thought you had to explicitly specify to use `gnuplot`, otherwise the `pgf` math engine would be used.

Comment: @PeterGrill That's the difference between `plot` and `plot function`.

Comment: Ahhh, yes I was thinking of `pgfplots` where you use `\addplot gnuplot`. I think I had decided a long time ago to do plots only in `pgfplots`, so totally forgot about this.. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @PeterGrill The give-away is the appearance of `.table` files after the run.

Answer (score 2):

Alan's answer is pretty much how I did it: I'd like to share some additional details.

It took me a while to work this one out. I had `latex` talk to `gnuplot` on my linux machine without doing anything, but struggled on Mac OS X. So for the record (most likely my future self), I'd like to summarize the various pieces of information I gathered from numerous searches.

1. Download the gnuplot sources from http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/
2. Unpack in a temporary directory
3. cd into the directory
4. At the terminal command line:

   ```
   ./configure --with-readline=builtin
   ```

   4b. If you get the following error:

   ```
   configure: error: in `/opt/gnuplot-4.6.4':
   configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
   ```

   Get command_line_tools_os_x_mountain_lion_for_xcode__october_2013.dmg from:

   https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/command_line_tools_os_x_mountain_lion_for_xcode__october_2013/command_line_tools_os_x_mountain_lion_for_xcode__october_2013.dmg

   This requires an appleid for download. Setting up an appleid is a great pain (I found a copy for direct download by searching pastebin).

   The `command line tools` are much smaller than `XCode` and should be sufficient to install and run `gnuplot`.

   After 4b go back to 4. and try again.

   4c. At some point you may need `XQuartz`. `XQuartz` is the new `X11`, a window emulator in which `gnuplot` can run and plot. Download from the `XQuartz` project: http://xquartz.macosforge.org. Because older applications still look for `XQuartz` by the name of `X11`. Make a link from `XQuartz` to `X11` by running:

   ```
   sudo ln -sf /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/ /Applications/Utilities/X11.app
   ```

   To get `gnuplot` to automatically run in `XQuartz`:

   ```
   echo "export GNUTERM='x11'" >> .bash_profile
   ```

   After 4. is completed, got to 5.
5. Command line:

   ```
   make
   ```
6. command line:

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```
7. Add gnuplot to the PATH:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/paths
   ```

   add the following line to the paths and save: `/usr/local/libexec/gnuplot`
8. Test

   ```
   gnuplot
   plot sin(x) with lines
   ```
9. Make LaTeX talk to gnuplot

   Create a config file in your `texmf-local` folder, named `texmf.cnf`, with the following:

   ```
   shell_escape_commands = \
   bibtex,bibtex8,\
   kpsewhich,\
   makeindex,\
   mpost,\
   repstopdf,\
   gnuplot,\
   ```

   The file must end with a blank line. Save or copy this file into the following directory:

   ```
   /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c
   ```

   Then update the TeX database. You should now be able to run the following code, for instance:

   [Recreating a guilloche with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46507/recreating-a-guilloche-with-tikz/46528#46528)
10. To call `gnuplot`, you need to allow `shell-escape`. Test with `latexmk`:

    ```
    latexmk --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape
    ```

    or with `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf`:

    ```
    latex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex: dvips -o %.ps %.dvi: ps2pdf %.ps
    ```

    There are several hints and explanations here:

    [Setting up LaTeX -> DVIPS -> PS2PDF with Shell-Escape (in TeXStudio)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160648/setting-up-latex-dvips-ps2pdf-with-shell-escape-in-texstudio)

Answer (score 0):

Using OSX Mountain Lion you have to install aquaterm and X11 or Xquartz first.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you please give a little bit more details? What are aquaterm and Xquartz?

Comment: SOLUTION:

first you have to install
X11
http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/
Than Aquaterm
http://sourceforge.net/projects/aquaterm/
After the installation you have to go to preferences (cmd ,) in TEXSHOP and add after: => 
Latex: pdflatex --shell-escape
Good luck and have fun, now it is even working for me =)
Concerning your question, i do not know what these programms do but it is working for me, when somebody elso knows more details i would be happy to hear about them too